# how to use Memcache with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached

I  using symfony 2 and I want to use Memcache with it but the problem is I can't find any explain for Memcache I just found for memcached so are they the same setup steps ? I added this lines to install Memcache on symfony?

config.yml

```
framework:
  session:
    handler_id: session.handler.memcached
```

for parameters.yml

```
parameters:   
  memcached_host: 127.0.0.1
  memcached_port: 11211
  memcached_prefix: custom_key_
  memcached_expire: 14400
```

services.yml

```
services:
  session.handler.memcached:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler
    arguments: [ "@session.memcached", { prefix: '%memcached_prefix%', expiretime: '%memcached_expire%' } ]


services:
  session.memcached:
    class: Memcached
    arguments:
      persistent_id: %memcached_prefix%
    calls:
      - [ addServer, [ %memcached_host%, %memcached_port% ]]



services:
  session.memcached:
    class: Madisoft\AppBundle\Utils\MemcachedWrapper
    arguments:
      persistent_id: '%memcached_prefix%'
    calls:
      - [ addServer, [ '%memcached_host%', '%memcached_port%' ] ]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is only one `Memcached` software, and it's the one available at https://memcached.org/.

There are two well-known `PHP` libraries for `Memcached`, called `memcache` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and `memcached` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php), so this is probably where your confusion comes from.

To use `Memcached` with Symfony 2 I suggest to use an external bundle by LeaseWeb which provides all the required documentation: https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle.

Starting with Symfony 3.3 there will be a native `Memcached` adapter: see http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-memcached-cache-adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm usinf Symfony 3.4 and here is my config.yml:

```
parameters:
    session_memcached_host: localhost
    session_memcached_port: 11211
    session_memcached_prefix: sess
    session_memcached_expire: 100 # this is in seconds

framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.memcached
```

and services.yml:

```
services:
    session.memcached:
        class: Memcached
        arguments:
            # Just remember to comment out below line or even remove whole arguments section
            # persistent_id: %session_memcached_prefix%
        calls:
            - [ addServer, [ %session_memcached_host%, %session_memcached_port% ]]

    session.handler.memcached:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@session.memcached", { prefix: %session_memcached_prefix%, expiretime: %session_memcached_expire% }]
```

With above configuration I store sessions in Memcached server (to be precise AWS ElasticCache Memcached).

If you want to play with Memcached, here is what I use to store my custom data:

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter;

$client = MemcachedAdapter::createConnection('memcached://localhost');
$cache  = new MemcachedAdapter($client, $namespace = '', $defaultLifetime = 0);
$item   = $cache->getItem('itemName');

if (!$item->isHit()) {
    // Item does not exist
    $item
        ->set($data)
        ->expiresAfter(10) // in seconds
    ;
    $cache->save($item);
} else {
    // Item exists
    $cachedItem = $item->get();
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: What if I want to store something per session? You last example stores data that every user can get. What If I want to store data for each user (like what native sessions do)? What happens if the user doesn't send the PHPSESSID?